# Quickbooks Desktop SDK Perofrmance

Tags: c#, sdk, quickbooks

We are using the QuickBooks SDK to communicate with QuickBooks desktop.

It could take very long (like more then about two minutes) to retrieve results from QuickBooks , or to update a single record,
so my question is as follow:
 is this a normal behavior?,
does anyone have a workaround for this problem ?

more info on our QB file its about 200 megabyte  and the file is stored over a local network .

Answer (score 2):

The QB desktop SDK is a nightmare, developed by an XML enthusiast who doesn't understand OOP.  The documentation actually argues with users about why it's better that things are done this way.  To be fair to the SDK team, they inherited an ancient, homebrew datafile system (that was probably created by generalist programmers) and had limited options.  QB Online is essentially Intuit's effort to re-engineer the backend, hopefully using proven RDBMS products this time!

So, to answer your question directly, the only workaround I know of is to dump QBD for QBO or another accounting platform.

Comment: I'm trying to write a simple program to find an invoice by reference then see if it is paid and just getting the SDK COM components to even work in C# is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

> is this a normal behavior?

For many situations, yes. You didn't really give much in the way of specifics, so there's not really much else to say here.

> does anyone have a workaround for this problem ?

The same solutions anyone would have for any other resource- or time- intensive job.

Batch jobs. Caching. Async communication.